# How to HLS-live-stream incoming batches of individual frames, "appending" to a m3u8 playlist in real time, with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, video.js, hls.js

## **My overall goal:**

### Server-side:

- I have batches of sequential, JPEG-encoded frames (8-16) arriving from time to time, generated at roughly 2 FPS.
- I would like to host an HLS live stream, where, when a new batch of frames arrives, I encode those new frames as h264 `.ts` segments with `ffmpeg`, and have the new `.ts` segments automatically added to an HLS stream (e.g. `.m3u8` file).

### Client/browser-side:

- When the `.m3u8` is updated, I would like the video stream being watched to simply "continue", advancing from the point where new `.ts` segments have been added.
- I do not need the user to scrub backwards in time, the client just needs to support live observation of the stream.

## **My current approach:**

### Server-side:

To generate the "first" few segments of the stream, I'm attempting the below *(just command-line for now to get ffmpeg working right, but ultimately will be automated via a Python script)*:

For reference, I'm using ffmpeg **version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1**.

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 2 -i /frames/batch1/frame_%d.jpg \
       -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryfast -g 2 \
       -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 4 -segment_wrap 4 -segment_list_flags +live video/stream.m3u8
```

where the `/frames/batch1/` folder contains a sequence of frames (e.g. frame_01.jpg, frame_02.jpg, etc...). This already doesn't appear to work correctly, because it keeps adding `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` to the end of the `.m3u8` file, which as I understand is not correct for a live HLS stream - here's what that generates:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream0.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream1.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
stream2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I can't figure out how to suppress `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` here - this is **problem #1**.

Then, to generate subsequent segments (e.g. when new frames become available), I'm trying this:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 2 -start_number 20 -i /frames/batch2/frame_%d.jpg \
       -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryfast -g 2 \
       -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 4 -segment_wrap 4 -segment_list_flags +live video/stream.m3u8
```

Unfortunately, this does not work the way I want it to. It simply overwrites `stream.m3u8`, does and does not advance `#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE`, it does not index the new `.ts` files correctly, and it also includes the undesirable `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` - this is the output of that command:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream0.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream1.ts
#EXTINF:3.000000,
stream2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Fundamentally, I can't figure out how to "append" to an existing `.m3u8` in a way that makes sense for HLS live streaming. That's essentially **problem #2**.

For hosting the stream, I'm using a simple Flask app - which appears to be working the way I intend - here's what I'm doing for reference:

```
@app.route('/video/<string:file_name>')
def stream(file_name):
    video_dir = './video'
    return send_from_directory(directory=video_dir, filename=file_name)
```

### Client-side:

I'm trying HLS.js in Chrome - basically boils down to this:

```
<video id="video1"></video>

...

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<script>
   var video = document.getElementById('video1');
   if (Hls.isSupported()) {
     var hls = new Hls();
     hls.loadSource('/video/stream.m3u8');
     hls.attachMedia(video);
     hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {
       video.play();
     });
   }
   else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
     video.src = '/video/stream.m3u8';
     video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
       video.play();
     });
   }
</script>
```

I'd like to think that what I'm trying to do doesn't require a more complex approach than what I'm trying above, but since what I'm trying to far definitely isn't working, I'm starting to think I need to come at this from a different angle. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

### **Edit:**

I've also attempted the same (again in Chrome) with `video.js`, and am seeing similar behavior - in particular, when I manually update the backing `stream.m3u8` (with no `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` tag), `videojs` never picks up the new changes to the live stream, and just buffers/hangs indefinitely.

```
<video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" muted="muted" controls>
    <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="/video/stream.m3u8">
</video>

...

<script>
    var player = videojs('video1');
    player.play();
</script>
```

For example, if I start with this initial version of `stream.m3u8`:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream0.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream1.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
stream2.ts
```

and then manually update it server-side to this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:3
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream3.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
stream4.ts
#EXTINF:3.000000,
stream5.ts
```

the video.js control just buffers indefinitely after only playing the first 3 segments (stream*.ts 0-2), which isn't what I'd expect to happen (I'd expect it to continue playing stream*.ts 3-5 once `stream.m3u8` is updated and `video.js` makes a request for the latest version of the playlist).

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the exact same questions @Rob

Comment: Never did solve it :(